# Magento Avoide Conditional Google Crawling

Tags: php, magento, seo, google-crawlers

Based on some product attribute, how do we tell Google, not to indexing product details page in Magento 1.X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try an observer method which listens to "controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after", and get inspired by

```
Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Model_Observer::convertLayerBlock
```

And then you can do the below in the observer method:

```
$front = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
$controller = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$action = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();

if ($front == 'catalog' && $controller == 'product' && $action == 'view') {
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product'); 
    if ($product && $product->getYourAttributeName() === "YourDesiredValue") {
        $observer->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setRobots('NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW');
    }
}
```